# Building a nested vector in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

My goal is to build a nested vector of dimension n consisting of a single element p. As an example let me choose n=2 and p=1, so the output would be:

```
   [[1 1] [1 1]]
```

Comment: And what if `n=3`? I'm not sure what you meant by `nested vector of dimension n`.

Comment: The input n is the row and column dimension of the matrix. In the case `n=3`                `[[1 1 1] [1 1 1] [1 1 1]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, you want something like this:

```
(defn square-matrix [n p]
  (->> p (repeat n) (repeat n)))
```

Or, if you need vectors (not seqs):

```
(defn square-matrix [n p]
  (->> p (repeat n) vec (repeat n) vec))
```

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is `(->> p (repeat n) vec (repeat n) vec)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn vec-of-dim [n e]
  (->> (repeat n e)
       (into [])
       (repeat n)
       (into [])))
```